# Legged Design for Desert/Dune Exploration

Tags: legged

I am currently in the process of writing a short sci-fi play about a team of researchers on Titan. With them, I'd like to have two four-legged robots (which would be actors in costumes). I'd like them to resemble Boston Dynamic's Spot or BigDog, with skinny legs and a bulky torso.

My question is: would the small foot design of those robots work well in desert areas? Walking through and over dunes, sandy beaches, that kind of thing. What's the best foot design for a legged robot traveling in sand?

Comment: from your question, it appears that you have never walked on sand. is that true?

Comment: Hey man, just asking a question, no need for the sass.

Comment: i was being serious .... there is a small chance that you do not have any experience with sand .... if you have no experience, then an explanation would be needed by whoever answers the question ... if you do have experience with sand, then it is kind of strange that you would ask if small diameter feet are suitable for sandy terrain